# Identify and remove leaked semaphores

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze

I'm currently facing the problem that on one of our Debian web servers a lot of semaphores are leaked. Is there a way to automatically remove all leaked semaphores? What I do now is to remove them manually using `ipcrm -s` which is quite tedious. I also want to avoid to restart the server which causes unwanted downtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143404/delete-all-shared-memory-and-semaphores-on-linux

Comment: What prevents you from taking the output of ipcs, filtering it with some grep and sed, and feeding that to ipcrm via a shell for loop or xargs? Crontab to taste...

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunately I can't mark a comment as correct answer...